# Can we assign hadoop application based on their type(MR,SPARK) into fair-scheduler queue?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-spark

Does fair-scheduler supports queue alloacation based on the app type?
Like all SPARK jobs go under Spark_Queue and MR jobs go under MR_Queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify YARN queue as --queue command line parameter, spark.yarn.queue Spark configuration parameter, or SPARK_YARN_QUEUE environment variable when submitting/running Spark jobs.

Comment: Yes defining queue in configs work. But what if this is a shared cluster. And we don't have  control on queue setup from user side and they can submit to any queue . Do we have any option in fair-scheduler, which redirects application based on their app type? . Instead of user defining which queue their job should go.